# IIS FTP 8 Home Directory Provider Won't Fire

Tags: c#, iis, ftp

I'm building a custom IIS FTP authenticator designed to authenticate from a SQL Server table.  The table has the user name, password, and home directory and these are returned from a query.  All this seems to work fine in the authenticator, but when I try to implement the home directory provider, I don't ever get down into the folder that I specify - it seems the provider isn't actually called.  Similarly if I try to implement a post process to provide custom processing of uploaded files, that doesn't fire either.  I'm stumped because I figured I've registered everything correctly or the authentication method would not run - so why aren't the other two executing?

I've scaled down my code so that I'm just writing to a text file so I can tell whether the method are firing.  Authentication works, the others don't.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.Web.FtpServer;

namespace MyCustomFtpExtension
{
    public class DatabaseAuthenticator : BaseProvider,
        IFtpAuthenticationProvider,
        IFtpRoleProvider, IFtpHomeDirectoryProvider, IFtpPostprocessProvider,
        IFtpLogProvider
    {
        private readonly string _logfile = Path.Combine(@"c:\test", "logs", "FtpExtension.log");
        public bool AuthenticateUser(string sessionId, string siteName, string userName, string userPassword,
            out string canonicalUserName)
        {
            canonicalUserName = userName;

            var result = DatabaseHelper.Authenticate(userName, userPassword);
            if (result)
            {
                LogMessage("Login Success: " + userName);  //this message appears
            }
            else
            {
                LogMessage("Login Failure: " + userName);
            }
            return result;
        }

        string IFtpHomeDirectoryProvider.GetUserHomeDirectoryData(
            string sessionId,
            string siteName,
            string userName)
        {
            LogMessage("In ftp home directory");  //this message never appears

            return @"c:\temp\test";
        }

        public FtpProcessStatus HandlePostprocess(FtpPostprocessParameters postProcessParameters)
        {

            LogMessage("Running Post Process");  //this message never appears
            return FtpProcessStatus.FtpProcessContinue;
        }

        public bool IsUserInRole(string sessionId, string siteName, string userName, string userRole)
        {
            return true; // I don't care about this - if they authenticate, that's all I need.
        }


        //to keep the sample short I took out the log provider - it was copy / paste from Microsoft's example

        //this is a quick and dirty output so I can see what's going on (which isn't much)
        private void LogMessage(string logEntry)
        {
            using (var sw = new StreamWriter(_logfile, true))
            {
                // Retrieve the current date and time for the log entry.
                var dt = DateTime.Now;

                sw.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}\tMESSAGE:{2}",
                    dt.ToShortDateString(),
                    dt.ToLongTimeString(),
                    logEntry);
                sw.Flush();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a setting I didn't notice before in IIS Manager under FTP Authorization Rules.  I had to change the setting there to indicate my custom assembly.  Once I did that, all the methods fired, I see all my messages in my text file, and now I have another error.  So back to researching I go.  But that's why they weren't firing.